# How and where do I save QSettings on Android?

Tags: android, qt, qsettings

I am starting to make a settings form for my program but I'm kinda stuck with the setting data. I can make a [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html) instance but what am I supposed to do with it then?

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QSettings settings;
settings.setValue("test", QVariant((int)42));
// Now what?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you don't need to know where the settings are stored.
Usual using of QSettings: you need to set your organization name well as the name of your application. While saving you need to set section and key, and a parameter.

```
//set names
QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("MySoft");
QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Star Runner");
//...
QSettings settings;
//saving
settings.setValue("MySection/MyKey", 42);
//loading: section, key, and default value (default value will be used if the setting doesn't exist)
int val = settings.value("MySection/MyKey", 0).toInt();
```

**Update**

```
//Perhaps, for Android it is necessary to call a function
settings.sync();
```

(From the documentation:

> ```
> void QSettings::sync()
> ```
>
> Writes any unsaved changes to permanent
>   storage, and reloads any settings that have been changed in the
>   meantime by another application. This function is called automatically
>   from QSettings's destructor and by the event loop at regular
>   intervals, so you normally don't need to call it yourself

)

Comment: What does it mean "automatically"? While saving with QSettings you need to call setValue() for each variable (with unique pair section-key). And you don't need to do somthing else

Comment: Saving means the setting actually gets written somewhere outside program memory (eg. a file). So what I'm asking is whether this happens automatically and if so, I wonder when... Otherwise I need to know how to save the settings (eg. to a file, system registry or whatever is Android using).

Comment: No, you don't need to do somthing else than invoking setValue(). QSettings will automatically make writing to a registry (or to a file, etc.). UPD: my be on Android need settings.sync();

Comment: And that Update: `settings.sync();` means what exactly?

Comment: Perhaps, may be for Android it is necessary to call a function settings.sync() after saving. It my be needed if you want to **load** some **saved** settings before the QSettings's destructor will be called